# CSS Flip book style fading webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a bit new to CSS and HTML codding but there is a button on the center of the screen. When you click the button it needs to fade out to show a few more buttons. Almost like a flip book every time you click the button it will go in a order to another set of button. A button appearing will fade in and buttons going out will fade out. I need some help on how to do this. I am stuck trying to fade the buttons and having them work like a flip book. Thanks!

HTML - http://pastebin.com/ApH8mG48

CSS - http://pastebin.com/PX66m4gy

Comment: We will definitely help you but first you need to at least try something with code!! At least post some html to show how the structure is and what kind of buttons you want to fade in or out `onclick` of which!

Comment: For future reference, using site like jsfiddle.net and plnkr.co will allow you to include links to [near] working examples of your code.